# A function with no singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a result in complex analysis which says that a function which has no singularity in the finite part of the plane or at infinity is constant. Is this result applicable to the function $e^{-1/z^2}$?

Comment: No singularity ? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5E(-1%2Fz%5E2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not defined at $z=0$ and cannot be continuously extended to $z=0$. To see this, consider the sequence $a_n=\frac in$, which converges to $0$ and notice that $$e^{-\frac1{a_n^2}}=e^{n^2}\overset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong -- $f(z) = e^{-1/z^2}$ has an awesome singularity at $z = 0$. You are probably only thinking of the real-number version of this function, not the complex version.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop the function as the Laurent series

$$1-\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{2z^4}-\frac1{3!z^6}+\cdots$$

which shows an essential singularity at the origin.